# Replace any (.) periods with escape backslashes so I can select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some elements with (.) periods in them and I need to select them but I need some escape characters to do so I believe.  How can I sure that my string that may have a period in it will be escaped properly. Something like this I guess?

```
var title = "User1.Title";
var string = //replace any periods with escape sequence?
$('#'+string).show();
```

It may have more than one (.) period, hopefully not but if I can replace all (.) periods so I can do my selection that would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
$('#'+string.replace(/\./g, "\\.")).show();
```

Comment: `string.replace(".", "\\.")` replaces only the first period in your string. To replace all of them use `s.replace(/\./g, "\\.")`. Then also stuff like "User1.Title.Subtitle" works.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this...

```
$("[id="+string+"]").show();
```

...but the problem with this guy is that is not that fast since it will traverse the entire DOM tree looking for every guy with that id, not only one.

You could also do this...

```
$('#'+string.replace(".", "\\.")).show();
```

.. that jQuery will pre-parse that selector and use *document.getElementById* behind the scenes.

You could also do this

```
$(document.getElementById(string)).show();
```

... wich yelds the same effect and you don't have to worry about CSS special characters.
Just be careful with IE(6 and 7) and Opera wich selects elements not only by it's ID but also by it's name.

Comment: I found the first solution here worked for me. n combinations of escapes and replaces weren't working when adjusting css properties using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$("[id='"+string+"']").show()
```

no need to escape it if you specify it as a property--jquery parses it differently.

Comment: You were close, @duckyflip, but it's not just about it being an id.  jquery parses any property's string differently.  You forgot the quotes around the string.